# Getting undefind data outside of subscribe in angular 14

Tags: angular, observable

I'm facing undefined data outside of subscribe, but it's getting inside of subscribe. I know, it's because of the Observable behavior. But how can I resolve this?

**edit.ts**

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    let product
    this.productId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')

    if (this.productId) {
      this.productService
        .getProductDetails(this.productId)
        .subscribe((response) => {
          product = response.data
          console.log(product)
        })
    }
    console.log(product)
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      productName: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      type: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      model: new FormControl(null)
    })
  }
```

**service.ts**

```
  getProductDetails(id: string) {
    return fromFetch(`http://localhost:3000/product/${id}`).pipe(
      switchMap((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json()
        } else {
          return of({ error: true })
        }
      })
    )
  }
```

Here, I want to access the product outside of subscribe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the `subscribe` part will execute asynchronously, whereas the `console.log` outside the subscribe is synchronous. So there is no way to access the output of subscribe, outside of the subscribe. instead, move the code inside the subscribe.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    let product
    this.productId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')

    if (this.productId) {
      this.productService
        .getProductDetails(this.productId)
        .subscribe((response) => {
          product = response.data
          console.log(product)
          this.form.patchValue(product);
        })
    }
      

    this.form = new FormGroup({
        productName: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
        type: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
        model: new FormControl(null)
    })
  }
```

Reference to understand [synchronous and asynchronous in javascript](https://wsvincent.com/javascript-event-loop/)

Comment: I want to access it from outside, don't want to create the form inside subscribe

Comment: @A'xon updated my answer! initialize the form, after subscribe completed, it will load the values.

Comment: it works perfectly! thanks for the quick reply, I will learn about the patchValue() function, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily *need* to access it outside of the subscribe handler, you can just build the form when the product becomes available:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.paramMap
    .pipe(
      filter((map) => !!map.get('id')),
      // only if you still need this as a property
      tap((productId) => (this.productId = productId)),
      switchMap((productId) =>
        this.productService.getProductDetails(productId)
      ),
      map((response) => response.data)
    )
    .subscribe((product) => this.buildProductForm(product));
}

buildProductForm(product: any): void {
  this.form = new FormGroup({
    productName: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
    type: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
    model: new FormControl(null),
  });
}
```